# Clear Specific Textboxes ASPX page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I'm having trouble trying to clear these banking and routing numbers that are in a textbox on an aspx page.  I've seen it used where they would just specify the ID of the textbox and do a textbox.text = String.Empty().  But that doesn't seem to work here. Maybe I'm using the wrong ID??  I also tried using JQuery .val("") but that didn't seem to work either.

Here's the code, i'd like to clear both Routing and Account text fields on click of a button:

```
     <div id="DivUser1BankInfo" class="labelAndTextboxContainer">
            <div class="labelContainer">
            <asp:Label CssClass="rightFloat" ID="User1LabelRoutingNumber" runat="server" Text="Routing #:"></asp:Label><br />
                </div>
                    <div class="textboxContainer">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="User1TextRoutingNumber" CssClass="leftFloat " runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Width="180px" 
                                        Text='<%# Bind("User1BankRoutingNumber") %>'
                                        Visible='<%#  ApexRemington.BLL.VendorBLL.ShowUser1BankInfo((string)Eval("User1BankInfoEditUser")) %>' /><br />
                    </div>
            <div class="labelContainer">
            <asp:Label CssClass="rightFloat" ID="User1LabelAccountNumber" runat="server" Text="Account #:"></asp:Label><br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="textboxContainer">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="User1TextAccountNumber" CssClass="leftFloat " runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Width="180px" 
                                        Text='<%# Bind("User1BankAccountNumber") %>'
                                        Visible='<%#  ApexRemington.BLL.VendorBLL.ShowUser1BankInfo((string)Eval("User1BankInfoEditUser")) %>' /><br />
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="clearButton1">Clear</button>

                    <div class="button">
                    <asp:Button ID="User1ClearBankInfo" runat="server" Text="Reset"
                                        Visible='<%#  ApexRemington.BLL.VendorBLL.ShowUser1BankInfo((string)Eval("User1BankInfoEditUser")) %>'  OnClick="clearFields_btn"/><br />
                    </div>
```

The OnClick= "clearFields_btn" code behind =

```
protected void clearFields_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post the code you have already tried in the 'clearFields_btn' handler, please? That way we might be able to see if what you did contains incorrect code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with ASP.NET in a little while, but I think you may want the `OnClientClick` event, not `OnClick`. `OnClientClick` is for client-side code (your jQuery/JavaScript) and `OnClick` is for server-side code (your C# or VB.NET).

You'd also want your `OnClientClick` event method to return false, or the server-side code will also fire.

So I think you want something like:

```
    <asp:Button ID="User1ClearBankInfo" runat="server" Text="Reset"
    Visible='<%#  ApexRemington.BLL.VendorBLL.ShowUser1BankInfo((string)Eval("User1BankInfoEditUser")) %>
     OnClientClick="clearText();"/>
```

And then `clearText` would look like this:

```
    <script>
    function clearText()
    {

          //our two IDs         

           $('input[id*="User1TextRoutingNumber"]').each(function(index) {
                $(this).val('');
            });
           $('input[id*="User1TextAccountNumber"]').each(function(index) {
                $(this).val('');
            });

           return false;
    }
    </script>
```

EDIT: shoot, I see my mistake. Fixed the code to clear the text of the textbox, not the button ("this").

Edit: removed the space from the "clear" text val.

EDIT: Made search a little more flexible, less dependent on GridView or no GridView.

Comment: Adding `this` to a OnClientClick of a button will not clear a TextBox. Second `$("#" + obj.id).val(" ");` will not clear it but put a space in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for this information, definitely good to know about the onClientClick part... When I added the function clearText() into the script heading it isn't picking up '<%=User1TextAccountNumber.ClientID%>' or the '<%=User1TextRoutingNumber.ClientID%>';  I'm still tinkering with it.

Comment: I updated this to just search for any inputs with IDs containing your textboxes' IDs. Gridviews and other parent containers (for lack of better terminology) will add on to the IDs, so this should handle that. I tested it on my local box and it worked. Let me know.

Comment: Hooray!! :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var clear = function(textboxID){$('input[id*=' + textboxID + ']').val('');};
return false;
</script>

<button id="btClearText" onclick="javascript:return clear('txtName');">
```

but if you need a more specific answer then please post more information

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this. Assuming you want a client side solution (not very clear from your question).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearTextBox() {
            document.getElementById("<%= User1TextRoutingNumber.ClientID %>").value = "";
            //or
            $("#<%= User1TextRoutingNumber.ClientID %>").val("");
            }
    </script>
```

The `<%= User1TextRoutingNumber.ClientID %>` will ensure you get the correct ID for javascript/jQuery.

A server side solution would be:

```
protected void clearFields_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("User1TextAccountNumber") as TextBox;
            tb.Text = "";
        }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to create something similar to what you mentioned on the server side, but intellisense isn't picking up on that ID attribute.  Is it worth mentioning that everything is within an <ItemTemplate>?

Comment: Yes that is very much worth mentioning. I've updated my answer. It now uses `FindControl`. My example uses a GridView, if you use another type of control you have to modify the for-loop.